# sort function in python doesn't work for long list?

Tags: python, arrays, list, sorting, floating-point

```
a=['0', '0.05', '0.1', '0.15', '0.2', '0.25', '0.3', '0.35', '0.4', '0.45', '0.5', '0.55', '0.6', '0.65', '0.7', '0.75', '0.8', '0.85', '0.9', '0.95', '1', '1.05', '1.1', '1.15', '1.2', '1.25', '1.3', '1.35', '1.4', '1.45', '1.5', '1.55', '1.6', '1.65', '1.7', '1.75', '1.8', '1.85', '1.9', '1.95', '10', '10.05', '10.1', '10.15', '10.2', '10.25', '10.3', '10.35', '10.4', '10.45', '10.5', '10.55', '10.6', '10.65', '10.7', '10.75', '10.8', '10.85', '10.9', '10.95', '11', '11.05', '11.1', '11.15', '11.2', '11.25', '11.3', '11.35', '11.4', '11.45', '11.5', '11.55', '11.6', '11.65', '11.7', '11.75', '11.8', '11.85', '11.9', '11.95', '12', '12.05', '12.1', '12.15', '12.2', '12.25', '12.3', '12.35', '12.4', '12.45', '12.5', '12.55', '12.6', '12.65', '12.7', '12.75', '12.8', '12.85', '12.9', '12.95', '13', '13.05', '13.1', '13.15', '13.2', '13.25', '13.3', '13.35', '13.4', '13.45', '13.5', '13.55', '13.6', '13.65', '13.7', '13.75', '13.8', '13.85', '13.9', '13.95', '14', '14.05', '14.1', '14.15', '14.2', '14.25', '14.3', '14.35', '14.4', '14.45', '14.5', '14.55', '14.6', '14.65', '14.7', '14.75', '14.8', '14.85', '14.9', '14.95', '15', '15.05', '15.1', '15.15', '15.2', '15.25', '15.3', '15.35', '15.4', '15.45', '15.5', '15.55', '15.6', '15.65', '15.7', '15.75', '15.8', '15.85', '15.9', '15.95', '16', '16.05', '16.1', '16.15', '16.2', '16.25', '16.3', '16.35', '16.4', '16.45', '16.5', '16.55', '16.6', '16.65', '16.7', '16.75', '16.8', '16.85', '16.9', '16.95', '17', '17.05', '17.1', '17.15', '17.2', '17.25', '17.3', '17.35', '17.4', '17.45', '17.5', '17.55', '17.6', '17.65', '17.7', '17.75', '17.8', '17.85', '17.9', '17.95', '18', '18.05', '18.1', '18.15', '18.2', '18.25', '18.3', '18.35', '18.4', '18.45', '18.5', '18.55', '18.6', '18.65', '18.7', '18.75', '18.8', '18.85', '18.9', '18.95', '19', '19.05', '19.1', '19.15', '19.2', '19.25', '19.3', '19.35', '19.4', '19.45', '19.5', '19.55', '19.6', '19.65', '19.7', '19.75', '19.8', '19.85', '19.9', '19.95', '2', '2.05', '2.1', '2.15', '2.2', '2.25', '2.3', '2.35', '2.4', '2.45', '2.5', '2.55', '2.6', '2.65', '2.7', '2.75', '2.8', '2.85', '2.9', '2.95', '20', '20.05', '20.1', '20.15', '20.2', '20.25', '20.3', '20.35', '20.4', '20.45', '20.5', '20.55', '20.6', '20.65', '20.7', '20.75', '20.8', '20.85', '20.9', '20.95', '21', '21.05', '21.1', '21.15', '21.2', '21.25', '21.3', '21.35', '21.4', '21.45', '21.5', '21.55', '21.6', '21.65', '21.7', '21.75', '21.8', '21.85', '21.9', '21.95', '22', '22.05', '22.1', '22.15', '22.2', '22.25', '22.3', '22.35', '22.4', '22.45', '22.5', '22.55', '22.6', '22.65', '22.7', '22.75', '22.8', '22.85', '22.9', '22.95', '23', '23.05', '23.1', '23.15', '23.2', '23.25', '23.3', '23.35', '23.4', '23.45', '23.5', '23.55', '23.6', '23.65', '23.7', '23.75', '23.8', '23.85', '23.9', '23.95', '24', '24.05', '24.1', '24.15', '24.2', '24.25', '24.3', '24.35', '24.4', '24.45', '24.5', '24.55', '24.6', '24.65', '24.7', '24.75', '24.8', '24.85', '24.9', '24.95', '25', '25.05', '25.1', '25.15', '25.2', '25.25', '25.3', '25.35', '25.4', '25.45', '25.5']
a.sort()
print (a)
```

Comment: Where the problem is ? Your list is already sorted as an input, and the result is correct. Please be aware that you are sorting strings, and it works differently than with floats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert your list in a list of float, not of string

```py
a = [*map(float, a)] #  [*map(float, a)] is equivalent to list(map(float, a))
a.sort()
print(a)
```

Should work.

If you want to convert it back to str you can do:

```py
a = [*map(str,a)]
```

OR, if you don't want trailing zeros:

```py
a = [*map(lambda c: str(round(c,2)).rstrip('0').rstrip('.'), a)]
```

As pointed by ShadowRanger, if you want it to keep it in str without converting it in Float at any time you can do

```py
a.sort(key = float)
```

Or

```py
a = a.sorted(key = float)
```

Comment: thanks the sorting work very well but I need to keep the same old name of each component of the list (keeping the same round of each list component)

Comment: When I convert it back to str, the round of some item changes.
for exemple the old name is '2' ,it will be '2.0'.
How can I keep the same round of each item ?

Comment: Yes of course! I'll edit my answer

Comment: If they want it to be unmodified `str` before and after, they shouldn't convert it back-and-forth at all, just call `a.sort(key=float)` on the original, unmodified `list` of `str`, and it will do the conversion (for comparison purposes) for you, while maintaining the original values.